# SOCKS5 is there encryption between client and proxy server?

Tags: proxy

I've read [the wikipedia article on socks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) and cannot find information about encryption between client and proxy-server. There is only information about authentication.

Is socks5 connection a plain-text?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SOCKS5 is just a transport protocol on top of TCP/UDP but below application layer.  Thus it's comparable with TCP and UDP, too.  There's no inherent encryption in SOCKS, but you application has to care about this (it's not a VPN technology, but a proxy at last).  If you want encryption, the protocol you speak inside of the SOCKS-channel has to provide it.

Comment: Alternatively, the protocol SOCKS runs on top of can provide encryption. A very common way to use SOCKS is over SSH (built into OpenSSH) - in that scenario SOCKS would run over the encrypted SSH connection.

Comment: … but in this case you should remember that only the SSH connection is actually encrypted (SSH client to SSH server) — SSH doesn't ensure encryption between the SSH server (your eventual SOCKS proxy) and the actual destination.

Comment: @AndreasWiese: so does this mean that if authentication is enabled, the password is transmitted in plain text?

Comment: @kontextify the SSH password is not transmitted in plain text since the SSH connection is encrypted. But it is better to use SSH password / certificate key authentication instead of just password to prevent bruteforce attacks. Note that a SOCKS proxy made with an SSH tunnel does not support UDP.

Comment: @AndreasWiese: well, in a VPN it's the same